# Show / Hide divs based on search.keypress (filter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, filter

I have a webpage with lots of "cards" I want to filter away some cards as I type into the search field, and when I remove a character, show them again (all when empty).

My problem is that it does not seem to work properly, it is "1 character behind" what I write, it also dont show the cards when I remove characters.

It also wont work when I finally write the whole criteria, it will find 3-4 cards when I am missing some letters.

This is the code I have atm:

```
$('#search').keypress(function(){
        $( ".champion" ).each(function( index ) {
            if ( $( this ).find('.name-tag').text().toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search').val().toLowerCase(), 0) == -1) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
```

I have also tried swapping it around:

```
$('#search').keypress(function(){
    $( ".champion" ).each(function( index ) {
        if ( $('#search').val().toLowerCase().indexOf($( this ).find('.name-tag').text().toLowerCase()) == -1) {
            $(this).css('opacity', '0.7');
        } else {
            $(this).css('opacity', '1');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Better create fiddle for the same. It will help us to quickly solve your problem. (jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by delaying the event by about 10ms, the user won't notice a difference, but it'll help you on your side.

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9f9yqma/) for your problem.

Here's what it basically does:

```
$(function () {

    var input = $("#entry");
    input.keydown(function () {
        // doesn't matter if you create an anonymous method or a regular method, only the setTimeout is of value

        setTimeout(function () {
            var s = $("#show");
            s.text(input.val());            
        }, 10);

    });
});
```

Your second problem is based on the keypress event which seems to not capture the backspace key. You're better of with using the `keydown` event handler as this does capture every key.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using "keypress", it will always give you the value which is "1 character behind". Better use "keyup" event.

I think you are trying to toggle the opacity based on entered search text. If its the same what you are looking for, Check this fiddle :

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/o77721kv/)

JS Code :

```
$(function () {

    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var $target = $("#target"); $target.find("li.champion").css("opacity", "0.7");
        $target.find("li.champion:contains('"+this.value+"')").css("opacity","1");
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="type in here" />

<ul id="target">
    <li class="champion">
        <span class="name-tag">abcd</span>
    </li>
    <li class="champion">
        <span class="name-tag">abcd</span>
    </li>
    <li class="champion">
        <span class="name-tag">deds</span>
    </li>
    .....

</ul>
```

Here is how its done :

1. Add "onKeyUp" event listener on "search" field
2. Using jQuery ":contains" selector we are setting the opacity to "1" for the matched element, and for others to "0.7"
   For more detail about ":contains" selector, [Check here](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the keyup / keydown and delay tips.

Turned out I had to store the values before doing the test, this is the final code:

```
$('#search').keydown(function () {     
setTimeout(function () {
            $( ".champion" ).each(function( index ) {
            var nameTag = $( this ).find('.name-tag').text().toLowerCase();
            var searchStr = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();

            if (nameTag.indexOf(searchStr) == -1) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });          
        }, 10);

});
```